# How to execute below T-SQL script into PowerShell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

Hi I am struggling into writing a PowerShell script to drop the database,  based on some conditions.I have SQL script running but facing too many syntax error when converting same script to PowerShell

```
DECLARE @Sql as NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT 'DROP DATABASE ['+ name + ']; ' FROM sys.databases WHERE name like '%Dev%'
and database_id < (SELECT max(database_id) FROM sys.databases where source_database_id IS NOT NULL  and name like '%Dev%' )
FOR XML PATH('')) EXEC sys.sp_executesql @Sql
```

I am new to PowerShell script so any help would be great.
I tried something like below but getting a syntax error in PowerShell

```
 $query= 'DECLARE @Sql as NVARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT 'DROP DATABASE ['+ name + ']; ' FROM sys.databases WHERE name like '%Dev%'
and database_id < (SELECT max(database_id) FROM sys.databases where source_database_id IS NOT NULL  and name like '%Dev%' )
FOR XML PATH('')) EXEC sys.sp_executesql @Sql '
    echo $query   
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance ''XXXX'   -Username 'XX' -Password 'XXXXX' -Query $query -QueryTimeout 600 -Verbose
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Convert it to Powershell"?

Comment: Show us your Powershell script.  There are quite a few ways that it can be done.

Comment: If your T-SQL script is working, perhaps you should ask a different question, how to execute it from PowerShell, rather than convert it to PowerShell.

Comment: @DanGuzman Yes that is what I am looking for how to execute in Powershell Could you plz help?

Comment: In your powershell, you've removed some of the single quotes in the dynamic statement... The statements aren't the same. For example, you have `SELECT DROP DATABASE [ +  name  + ];` in your powershell, and `SELECT 'DROP DATABASE ['+ name + ']; '` in your original SQL. This looks like typograghical error, where you haven't actually *checked* your code.

Answer (score 1):

I Just putted everything in "" and it worked.